# Google font @font-face not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I've read a lot of "@font-face not working" questions here, but none helped me out with my current problem.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started), I have to "Add a stylesheet link to request the desired web font(s)".

So in my HTML's **< head >**, I added:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then I tried to style my element by adding this bit of code in my HTML:

```
<div style="font-family: 'Damion', serif;">My text</div>
```

Damion Font: [image: Damion Font Sample]

Currently it displays "My Text" in Times New Roman.

Is it possible that a code snippet elsewhere in the HTML or CSS deactivates the @font-face?

Safari 9 (Yosemite).

Comment: it works in FF..btw which browser were you checked?

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/m0revpc0/. It's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your given code works fine. You can check the followings...

- This must needs an internet connection for downloading the css from
  the Google Fonts Server
- Re-check the the code with typing errors

or pls provide the browser and version

Comment: I added browser and version. Could there be a CSS or HTML code or tag that disables the @font-face?

Comment: its Working fine on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (8.0.8),
Pls check with your firewall / proxy / Internet Settings.